# Override swipe gesture on UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a UITableView. I have added to this table a UIGestureRecognizer that looks for a swipe on a cell, and enables editing on that table if it detects a swipe. When I swipe right, it does indeed enable editing on the table. However, when I swipe left, I get the default red delete button appear on the right side of the cell. How can I disable this default behavior, and make it so that if I swipe left OR right, I get editing on either way?

```
- (void)handleSwipeFrom:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    foldersTable.editing=YES;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer;
    recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];
    [foldersTable addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    [recognizer release];

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just return `UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone` in your `tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Answer (score 3):

There is a direction property on UISwipeGestureRecognizer. You can set that to both right and left swipes:

```
recognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
```

Comment: I get "direction not found of type UIGestureRecognizer"

Comment: You see where you put `UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer` ... Change that to `UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer`

Answer (score 0):

I am using another way to solve this problem.

```
NSMutableArray *tableViewGestures = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[self.tableView gestureRecognizers]];
[[tableViewGestures objectAtIndex:2] setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
NSLog(@"directions %@" , [tableViewGestures objectAtIndex:2] );

NSArray *newTableViewGestures = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:tableViewGestures];
[self.tableView setGestureRecognizers:newTableViewGestures];
```

I got the tableViewGestures NSArray and reset it.If I wanna use SwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRigth,I just need to set the direction again.It's easy.Right?